# How to link a linked list to a static array in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Consider:

```
    struct Package_Node
    {
        int bar_code;
        float package_weight;
        struct Package_Node *next_packaged;
    };

    struct Key_Node
    {
        int key;
        struct Package_Node *next_package;
    };

    int weightTemp = 0, barcodeTemp = 0, keyTemp = 0, N = 0, X = 0, max_value = 0, optionChosen = 0, optionChosenTwo = 0;
    float tempWeight;

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        do
        {
            cout << "1 - Enter Number of keys and the Max Value\n2 - Enter Number of Packages (N)\n";
            cout << "3 - Create Array of Keys\n4 - Organize Packages\n5 - Table Stats\n6 - Clean Table\n7 - Exit\n\n";
            cin >> optionChosen;

            switch(optionChosen)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    cout << "\nEnter Number of Keys:";
                    cin >>X;
                    cout <<"\nEnter Max Value of the Barcode: ";
                    cin >>max_value;
                    break;
                }

                case 2:
                {
                    cout << "\nEnter Number of Packages: ";
                    cin >> N;
                    //keyTemp=
                    break;
                }

                case 3:
                {
                    Key_Node keyMain[X];
                    for(int i=0;i<X;i++)
                    {
                        keyMain[i].key=i;
                        //cout << keyMain[i].key; //to see key values.
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case 4:
                {
                    Package_Node totalPackages[N];
                    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                    {
                        barcodeTemp = rand() % max_value + 1;
                        keyTemp = barcodeTemp % X;
                        tempWeight = rand() % 500 + 1;
                        totalPackages[i].bar_code=barcodeTemp;
                        totalPackages[i].package_weight=tempWeight;

                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                    {
                        cout << totalPackages[i].bar_code <<endl;
                        cout << totalPackages[i].package_weight << endl;
                    }
```

This is my code. I am trying to put the information of total packages[i] (dynamic array) and link it to keyMain (of Package_Node data type and static array). But I am totally lost here how to do so.

Also, is my declaration of the dynamic array "totalPackages" correct? Or should I not declare its size since this will grow according to the total number of packages entered by the user? `totalPackages` is supposed to be a linked list that grows as the program wants.

Comment: This code doesn't come close to compiling, much less running correctly (or even *incorrectly*). There are missing variable declarations (`totalPackages`), an incomplete `main()` (and `case`, and `switch`, and `do-while`). Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that amplifies your question.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added the totalPackages declaration which was apparently deleted at the time of the posting. The other parts are going to be worked at later, I am trying to figure out how do I point struct key_node keyMain's next_package pointer will point to the totalPackages[some number] pointer?

Comment: Still doesn't compile, and also, C++ doesn't support VLA (variable length array) declarations. Your implementation may  allow this, but it is non-standard. You'd be considerably closer to portable using a `std::vector<Package_Node>`. Even then, if you're supposed to be using a linked list as stated in the question I cannot see how you concluded a static array would be acceptable for whatever problem is being addressed.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, variables declared between curly braces `{}` are local: they "cease to exist" when running code outside the braces.

Your code looks like this:

```
        case 3:
        {
            Key_Node keyMain[X];
        }
        case 4:
        {
            Package_Node totalPackages[N];
        }
```

It is impossible to have one part of code access stuff declared in the other. To fix, declare stuff at the start of the main function:

```
int main()
{
    Key_Node keyMain[X];
    Package_Node totalPackages[N];
    ...
}
```

Now the declarations are bad, because they go before the user supplies the values `X` and `N`. To fix that, replace arrays by `std::vector`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Key_Node> keyMain;
    std::vector<Package_Node> totalPackages;
    ...
}
```

You will need to learn working with `std::vector` [see the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), especially `push_back` and `size`). In addition, look at the documentation of `std::list`; it might help you too.